# Python while loop speed

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, overhead

I would like it if someone could please explain to me why the following code has so much additional overhead. At 100k iterations, the speed is the same for either case (2.2 sec). When increasing to 1E6 iterations case "B" never finishes, while case "A" takes only 29 seconds.

**Case "A"**

```
while n is not 1:
    foo
```

**Case "B"**

```
while n > 1:
    foo
```

Complete code if of any help

```
def coll(n):
    count = 0
    # while n is not 1:
    while n > 1:
        count += 1
        if not n % 2:
            n /= 2
        else:
            n = 3*n + 1
    return count

for x in range(1,100000):
    count = coll(x)
```

Comment: Both versions with 100,000 iterations run in under 1 second for me. For 1,000,000 iterations, B runs in ~11 seconds, and A is still running.

Comment: The construction `n is not 1` is not in anyway equivalent to `n > 1`. The first form is not an arithmetic comparison and should not be used. The `is not 1` is a statement about object identity and is completely implementation dependent. That is `n != 1` is not necessarily equivalent to `n is not 1`. If you use undefined behavior, your program can do anything it wants, so don't.

Comment: Alan, are you sure you mean that B never finishes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant By "A never finishing I mean that I let the program run for 20 minutes without completion so I had to terminate it. I discovered that the IS NOT was causing my script to hang, and have replaced it with !=.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use `n > 1` or `n != 1`, not `n is not 1`. The fact that the latter works is an implementation detail, and obviously it's not working for you.

The reason it's not working is because there are values of `x` in your code that cause the Collatz sequence to go over the value of `sys.maxint`, which turns `n` into a `long`. Then, even when it ends up going back down to `1`, it's actually `1L`; a `long`, not an `int`.

Try using `while n is not 1 and repr(n) != '1L':`, and it'll work as you expect. But don't do that; just use `n > 1` or `n != 1`.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it was in my mind that != was similar to is not.  The clarification makes sense as why the code seemed to hang. Is there any reason that n >1 is prefered to n != 1 if both are appropriate for the loop structure?

Comment: @Alan, what makes you say that `n > 1` is preferred? I would use `n != 1`, as it seems to make more semantic sense to me, given the properties of the Collatz sequence. Their performance is practically identical in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in Python, `is` is extremely fast to check, as it uses referential equality, so all that needs to be checked is that two objects have the same memory location. Note that the only reason your code works is that most implementations of Python generally maintain a pool of the smaller integers, so that every `1` always refers to the same `1`, for example, where there may be multiple objects representing `1000`. In those cases, `n is 1000` would fail, where `n == 1000` would work. Your code is relying on this integer pool, which is risky.

`>` involves a function call, which is fairly slow in Python: `n > 1` translates to `n.__gt__(1)`.